# How to insert additional model without losing data stored on mysql

Tags: mysql, django, docker, migration

My django app has two model, for example model_A and model_B, and this app could run well on docker. The docker compose is following

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: ......
    volumes:
       .....
  db:
    image:mysql5.7
    volume:
       .......
  nginx:
     image:....
volumes:
  volume_mysql:
  .......
```

After running the app for a while, I want to add a model, for example model_C on the app,  exchanging app container to new one containing model_C.

```
docker-compose stop
docker rm app
docker rmi app
docker-compose up -d --build
```

And makemigrations/migrate process also work without any error message

```
docker exec app python manage.py makemigrations
docker exec app python manage.py migrate
```

On the other hand, I did not update the volume_mysql, because volume_mysql contained a lot of important data (I was reluctant to remove the volume, which resulted in loose all data)

When I tried accessing model_c (on admin page), however, error_message

> 1146, "Table 'race_record.result_model_C' doesn't exist"

was displayed.

I guess it seem to be because volume_mysql is old, having yet to contain ‘model_c’, although migrate process was done well.

So, how to add model_c without losing date stored on mysql

Comment: You do not need to delete an existing container just because you added a new Django model. Make sure your Django source is correctly reflected in the container with volumes. Then you can simply `exec` into your `app` container and run your migration for your new model, without losing any table or related information. Note: whether you delete an `app` container or not, it should not touch your database in your `db` container.

Comment: Are you sure your ModelC is imported properly? If not, it won't be visible to the makemigrations command, and nog migration will be add to create a ModelC table.
Check if you have 1. Added the app ModelC is located in to your INSTALLED_APPS setting. 2. ModelC is located in the app's models.py. 3. If you have models directory, make sure you import ModelC in the models/__init__.py

Comment: @NicoGriffioen Thank you for your comment. I checked your points and confirmed everything were done correctly. What's more I could see that Migration Class in app_container/my_project/result(Installed_APP)/migratoins/0001_initial.py created the model named 'Model_C'. So. I think the process of makemigration seem to be OK...maybe. Do you have any idea to solve it?